# Issue with MOUSE_MOVE and MOUSE_OUT applied to stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having an issue with MOUSE_OUT being called while it shouldn't. What I'm doing is quite simple: two images are shown when I move the mouse across the stage, and when the mouse leaves the stage they are hidden.

The problem is, that whenever the mouse hits the border of any movieclip on the stage, the MOUSE_OUT function gets called, hiding the two images. This means that whenever I move the mouse

My code (only the relevant parts are shown):

```
public class Slider extends MovieClip {
    var img1:Img1 = new Img1;
    var img2:Img2 = new Img2;
    var img1_hover:Img1_hover = new Img1_hover;
    var img2_hover:Img2_hover = new Img2_hover;

    public function Slider() {
        img1.alpha = 0;
        img2.alpha = 0;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showArrows);
    }
    function showArrows(e:MouseEvent) {
         img1.alpha = 1;
         img2.alpha = 1;

         stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideArrows);
    }
    function hideArrows(e:MouseEvent) {
         img1.alpha = 0;
         img2.alpha = 0;
    }
 }
```

Flash throws no errors. I am using a separate .as file (just one) and have no code inside of the action panel in the .fla.
Where there's stage.addEventListener, I also tried this., root. and nothing instead of stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the MOUSE_LEAVE event instead http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#event:mouseLeave

Alternatively, in the hideArrows function you can check the target of the event:

```
function hideArrows(e:MouseEvent) {
    If(e.target == stage){
         img1.alpha = 0;
         img2.alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrific, that helped, thanks a bunch! Well the alternative method didn't work but that's quite alright :). Only thing is that the mouse_leave event is also dispatched when right-clicking, but that's no biggie. Could you perhaps also tell me _why_ the mouse_out event doesn't work properly? I'm probably using it wrong, but I'd really like to know.